# How to run Selenium RC + PHPUnit + NetBeans remotely?

Tags: netbeans, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I have Selenium Server, PHPUnit and NetBeans up and running on a machine that I want to be my dedicated testing box.  How can I set it up to were I modify test cases (I already figured that part out) and tell the test machine to run the test remotely?

Comment: Check out the answer in a different question that I posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459223/how-to-run-a-test-in-phpunitselenium

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a continuous integration server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).  Usually CI servers are used to build an application on every commit to a repository, but it's just as easy to manually start a "build" that just consists of running all your tests (and recording the results, and running code coverage if you want, etc).

I found Jenkins to be really easy to set up (I followed a nice tutorial at http://blog.jepamedia.org/2009/10/28/continuous-integration-for-php-with-hudson) - the only extra work I had to do besides creating a build script was to make sure that Selenium RC is running on the test machine, and it sounds like you've already done that.

To make it even easier, if you set up Jenkins (or any other CI server, I'm sure) to build on a commit to your repository, then you don't even have to log onto the test machine to edit the tests - anybody can commit test changes, the CI server will run the tests, and everybody can see the results.  Not *quite* as important if you're developing solo, but still a handy trick.

Answer (score 0):

We can run the test cases from remote server and case will get execute into local machine. We have to follow the below steps,

Install phpunit and necessary packages in server
edit the test case and change host as local ip address ( use static ip address )
run the selenium RC in local server
run the test case in server
Test case will get execute into local machine.